# finding repetitions of integer X in an array and deleting them using pointers minus array

Tags: c

```
int A[50]; /* tableau donné */
int N; /* dimension du tableau */
int X; /* valeur à éliminer */
int *P1, *P2; /* pointeurs d'aide */

/* Saisie des données */
printf("Dimension du tableau (max.50) : ");

scanf("%d", &N);
for (P1 = A; P1 < A + N; P1++)
{
    printf("Elément %d : ", P1 - A);
    scanf("%d", P1);
}

printf("Introduire l'élément X à éliminer du tableau : ");

scanf("%d", &X);

/* Affichage du tableau */
for (P1 = A; P1 < A + N; P1++)
{
    printf("%d ", *P1);
}
printf("\n");

/* Effacer toutes les occurrences de X et comprimer : */
/* Copier tous les éléments de P1 vers P2 et augmenter */
/* P2 pour tous les éléments différents de X. */
for (P1 = P2 = A; P1 < A + N; P1++)
{
    *P2 = *P1;
    if (*P2 != X)
        P2++;
}

/* Nouvelle dimension de A */
N = P2 - A;

/* Edition du résultat */
for (P1 = A; P1 < A + N; P1++)
    printf("%d ", *P1);

printf("\n");
system("pause");
return 0;
```

"N=P2-A" how does this one line deletes all repetitions of X and shrinks the array, I can't seem to understand it . P2 points on P1 which basically points on the whole array. how is it that P2(adress)minus A(adress of the first case in the array). deletes the occ and shrinks it .

Comment: There is some code missing here at the beginning, and you have a lot of useless empty lines that make this hard to read. Plus, my guess is you've forgot some `{}` somewhere – and this is why the program is not behaving as expected. You'll see such problems very quickly by using your code editors "indent code" functionality. (if you're not using an editor that has "indent code", "autoformat code" or similar functionality, get one. For example, the free Visuals Studio Code IDE with the C/C++ extension has excellent support, but so does notepad++)

Comment: I promise, letting your IDE indent your code properly will help you. Not only will anyone who wants to read your code thank you, but you will instantly see a lot of structural problems!

Comment: It wasn't done by that one line, but by the previous loop. The array was shrunk by copying certain elements to a lower position in the same array, and this `N=P2-A` finishes the job by changing `N`  from the old length to the new length. Doing this with pointers isn't idiomatic: you would normally use array indexing.

Comment: ripe for a buffer overflow here. you aren't checking that they didnt enter more than 50...  you should malloc the size array that you need instead of precreating size 50 OR add a check that N is less than equal to 50.